# PhantomJS and Python error

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

Trying to run this with Python, Selenium and PhantomJS

```
add_to_cart = browser.find_element_by_class_name('button btn-cart')
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", add_to_cart)
```

But I'm getting the below error. I already tried find_element_by_xpath and ID, same error.

Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soleboxphantom.py", line 76, in <module>
    add_to_cart = browser.find_element_by_class_name('button btn-cart')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 712, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Compound class names not permitted","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"104","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:51049","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"class name\", \"sessionId\": \"2ae23860-e740-11e5-ab4b-f74b615c722a\", \"value\": \"button btn-cart\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/2ae23860-e740-11e5-ab4b-f74b615c722a/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
add_to_cart = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="button btn-cart"]')
```

as there should be no spaces in class name if you want to use `by_class_name`

Comment: Thanks @Andersson.  Now I have a similar issue File "soleboxphantom.py", line 94, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="button expand"]').click()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 258, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

Comment: I use this 

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="button expand"]').click()

It works with Chrome driver but not with PhantomJS.

Comment: I have a little experience with `PhantomJS` so you'd better open new ticket with this issue